# Passing Cursor Result to send_dbmail as a Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I've never worked with cursors before, and upon reading, this may not be the best approach, so by all means, makes suggestions.

I am attempting to pass the result set of a cursor to a query. Here's what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @PM varchar(50),
        @c1 as CURSOR
SET @c1 = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PM
    FROM PMtable

OPEN @c1;
FETCH NEXT FROM @c1 INTO @PM;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @emailBody nvarchar(max)
        SET @emailBody = 'SELECT * FROM othertable WHERE PM = ' + @PM + ' ORDER BY PM';
    
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = 'me@me.com',
        @subject = 'test',
        @query = @emailBody;

FETCH NEXT FROM @c1 INTO @PM;
END
CLOSE @c1;
DEALLOCATE @c1;
```

The idea is to send the @emailBody query result set as an email for every result in the cursor. For example, say the cursor returns three results: Bob, Jim, and Joe. I want to loop run the @emailBody query for each result from the cursor and send an email for each result.

When I run the query as is, I receive an error saying:

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Error formatting query, probably
> invalid parameters
>
> Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
> sp_send_dbmail, Line 504 [Batch Start Line 0]
>
> Query execution failed:
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVER, Line 9 Invalid column name
> 'Bob'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVER, Line 1 Invalid
> column name 'Bob'.

I have no clue what's going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add  `''`:

```
SET @emailBody='SELECT * FROM othertable WHERE PM = ''' + @PM + ''' ORDER BY PM';
```

Be aware of possible SQL Injection.

---

How it works:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVER, Line 9 Invalid column name 'Bob'.

```
SELECT * FROM othertable WHERE PM = Bob ORDER BY PM 
vs.
SELECT * FROM othertable WHERE PM = 'Bob' ORDER BY PM
```

Please keep in mind that `ORDER BY PM` for one value does not change anything.

Comment: Wow, what a simple solution! Exactly what I needed, thank you! I'll mark this as the solution once the time minimum time limit is met.